# Cant access an element from a TabControl DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

1- Copy and paste following code into **MainWindow.xaml** file.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Width="250" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Copy from RichTextBox1 to RichTextBox2"/>
    <TabControl Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem1">
            <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox1">
                <FlowDocument x:Name="FlowDocument1">
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run Text="England"/>
                        <LineBreak/>
                        <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="France"/>
                        <LineBreak/>
                        <Run Foreground="Red" Text="Germany"/>
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem2">
            <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1">
                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb1" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                    <Thumb.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox2" Width="400" Height="200">
                                <FlowDocument x:Name="FlowDocument2" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12">
                                    <Paragraph/>
                                </FlowDocument>
                            </RichTextBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Thumb.Template>
                </Thumb>
            </Canvas>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

2- Copy and paste following code into **code behind** file.

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myMemoryStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim FirstTextRange As New TextRange(RichTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd)
    FirstTextRange.Save(myMemoryStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage)
    myMemoryStream.Position = 0
    Dim myRichTextBox As New RichTextBox
    myRichTextBox = CType(Thumb1.Template.FindName("RichTextBox2", Thumb1), RichTextBox)
    Dim SecondTextRange As New TextRange(myRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, myRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd)
    SecondTextRange.Load(myMemoryStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage)
End Sub
End Class
```

3- Run this project, select **TabItem2**, click **Button1**, understand Copy from RichTextBox1 to RichTextBox2 is successfully done.

**My question is here;**

Run this project again, select **TabItem1**, click **Button1**, see this error: https://prnt.sc/mwjijx

As you can see;

If **TabItem2** is selected then there is no error,

If **TabItem1** is selected then there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `Thumb1` element is not fully created until you open the tab that contains it. Therefore, the `FindName` method can't find the `RichTextBox2` (so it returns `null`).

You can try forcing the `Thumb1` element to be fully created by calling its [`ApplyTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. Then call the `FindName` method:

```
Thumb1.ApplyTemplate()
myRichTextBox = CType(Thumb1.Template.FindName("RichTextBox2", Thumb1), RichTextBox)
```

Comment: @DannyScofield I added the call to `ApplyTemplate()`, the rest is the same. I don't know VB.NET, so I hope I used the correct syntax.